# If I don't have much content, how to get the footer at the bottom of the page but I don't want a sticky footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

There's two scenarios for my content

1)  I don't have much content so I want the footer at the bottom of the page.

2)  I have lots of content and I want the footer after all the content (i.e. not a sticky footer).

I've tried with CSS but I think because I've got some images and text floating I can't get it to work.

Can I fix the footer issue using javascript?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: Add snippets with your attempts, please.

Comment: What you explained is commonly referred to as a "sticky" footer (maybe you are confusing it with a "fixed" one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the most robust (and pretty simple) footer of that kind I've come across:

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Used successfully in different projects - tested down to IE6 and works in all modern browsers independently of all other content.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.  Just had to make a couple of minor changes such as min-height: 85%; and making it 8em instead of 4em but the code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

try this

**css**

```
body, html{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}

.wrapper{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.container{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom:100px;
}

.header{
    height:100px;
    background-color:#066;
}

.footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#006;
    width:100%;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="header">
            Header
        </div>

        <div class="body">

        </div>


    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>

</div>
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/8AuAn/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `min-height` on the content of the page. Without a lot of changes it will only work on normal screen resolutions (cause you will specify a `min-height` in px), but normally it's only desirable to push the footer down a normal amount for which `min-height` in pixels is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the shortest way:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <div id="content">         
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#header{
    height:100px;
    background-color:#00ff00;
    width:100%;
}

#content{
 width:100%;
 border:1px solid red;
 min-height:calc(100% - 200px);
 min-height:-moz-calc(100% - 200px);
 min-height:-webkit-calc(100% - 200px);
 min-height:-o-calc(100% - 200px);
}

#footer{
    height:100px;
    background-color:#0000ff;
    width:100%;
}
```